# React Native - Using "flex" inside a FlatList

Tags: react-native, flexbox, react-native-flatlist

I'm starting to learn React Native, and I'm trying to create grid of 3 columns with images. I've been using the `numColumns` prop of the FlatList to specify 3 columns, and then setting `flex:1` for my images so they should fill the space of the column. However `flex:1` makes none of my images appear, while trying `height:100,aspectRatio:1` shows all of my images in columns. Any idea why this is? My code is down below:

```
export default class ArtScrollView extends React.Component {
    _renderItem = (item) =>
        (
            <Image style={styles.art} source={{uri:item.item.imgFilePath}}/>
        )
    render() {
        return(
            <FlatList numColumns={3}
            data={Object.values(this.props.pods)}
            renderItem={this._renderItem}/>
        );
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    art:{
        height:100,
        aspectRatio:1,
        //flex:1, <- Having this instead of specifying the height doesn't work
        marginRight:10,
    }
  });
```

Comment: Have a look at the document https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/images.html#why-not-automatically-size-everything.

Answer (score -1):

- Auto-sizing images in ReactNative does not work. It just doesn't. **You need to know the dimensions of images before you show them.**
- It is quite easy to use `var {height, width} = Dimensions.get('window');` and use those as your **reference for your images' sizing.**
- **Use the inspector** and see (and understand) what FlatList actually renders for you. You may understand why things do not work (not just in this case but generally)

Comment: You can actually make an image fit the size of its container. If the container changes, the image will indeed change. Therefore there is no need to know the dimension of an image.

Comment: My answer is dtaed almost two years ago. I have not used much RN since then. Maybe things changed. Don't know.